# Реляционный запрос выбрасывает ошибку если в бд нету записи соответствующей реляционному свойству

Tags: php, yii, activerecord

Модель News связана с Files один к одному.
Пытаюсь выполнить реляционный запрос:

```
$model=News::model()->with('files')->findByPk($_GET['id']);
```

Если у меня есть в таблице files запись соответствующая `$_GET['id']`, то все ок.
Если же файла нету, то выбрасывает ошибку:

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in C:\...\yii\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1514
```

Пробовал использовать ленивую загрузку - то же самое.

Мне именно нужно, что бы при наличии файла его выбирало вместе с новостями, а при его отсутствии выбирало только новости.

Метод finByPk:

```
public function findByPk($pk,$condition='',$params=array())
{
    Yii::trace(get_class($this).'.findByPk()','system.db.ar.CActiveRecord');
    $prefix=$this->getTableAlias(true).'.';
    $criteria=$this->getCommandBuilder()->createPkCriteria($this->getTableSchema(),$pk,$condition,$params,$prefix);
    return $this->query($criteria);
}
```

Comment: Прототип функции findByPk() покажете?

Comment: findByPk - это встроенный метод CActiveRecord

Comment: Явно ошибка внутри функции. Т.е. необходимо смотреть версии библиотеки где ошибка пофиксина и обновляться до версии без ошибки. Либо переопределить кламс и самому пофиксить.

Comment: Вот внутренности findByPk если помогут: `public function findByPk($pk,$condition='',$params=array())
 {
  Yii::trace(get_class($this).'.findByPk()','system.db.ar.CActiveRecord');
  $prefix=$this->getTableAlias(true).'.';
  $criteria=$this->getCommandBuilder()->createPkCriteria($this->getTableSchema(),$pk,$condition,$params,$prefix);
  return $this->query($criteria);
 }`. Только я не в курсе, что именно не правильно работает

Comment: Напиши в вопрось читать тяжело

Comment: Есть подозрение, что ошибка возникает не в процессе запроса к БД, а где-то далее, где вы пытаетесь вывести данные несуществующей записи

Comment: А если у вас не всегда есть связь, то можно попробовать вместо with использовать leftJoin

Comment: Iaroslav Gashuk, вы правы. Обнаружил, что у меня в представлении было обращение к $model->files

Answer (score 1):

В представлении было обращение к $model->files